# I query firestore for a document and try to add it to an array, but the array returns empty

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, get

I am trying to get a user from a document meant to hold user data.  The document holds this data

```
First: "Josh"
Last: "Solders"
email: "example@gmail.com"
phone: "7865572525"
superAdmin: "on"
userID: "admin-1"
```

I run this function:

```
  export const getAdmins = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    var admins: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData[] = [];
    admin.firestore().collection("admin").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        var c = 0;
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            admins[c] = doc.data();
            c++;
            console.log(doc);
            console.log(admins[c]);
        });
    });
    return admins;
  })
```

and it returns to here:

```
                const getAdmins = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getAdmins');
                        // Passing params to data object in Cloud functinon
                getAdmins({}).then((results) => {
                    admins = results;
                    console.log("admins retrieved");
                    console.log(results);
                });
```

The function returns and the log shows that it accessed the file, however, the array returns empty.  I am not quite sure why this isn't returning properly unless the `local variable admins` can't be accessed once its inside `get` call.  I don't think that makes sense, but that is the best explanation for it myself.  I could use some help figuring out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement may run even before your promise is resolved as it's asynchronous. Your function is async so try using `await` instead of Promise chaining:

```js
export const getAdmins = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("admin").get()
  return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())
})
```

Also you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method instead to simplify the code.